# Group_concat in old MySQL version

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an old version of MySQL (4.0) and cannot use Group_Concat, or stored procedures. Does anybody know how I could concatenate these rows:

```
xxx || yyy        || zzz
xxx || abc        || eee
vvv || otherstuff || otherstuff
vvv || otherstuff || otherstuff
```

For it to be like that:

```
xxx || yyy || zzz || abc || eee
```

where every line is grouped by the ID (here:xxx, vvv, ....)? I have been on this problem for a while...

Comment: Does `||` indicate new column or string separator? Please edit your question. If you want string concatenation use `CONCAT_WS` and variables.

Comment: @lad2025 || is a column separator

Comment: @Strawberry If yes then  it is a `PIVOT`, not `GROUP_CONCAT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just replace `keyword_ids` with the column you are wanting to concat.
http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20955939/Mysql-group-concat-alternative-in-3-23-x.html

```
SELECT @prev_item_id := NULL;

SELECT  MAX(@keyword_ids := IF(@prev_item_id = item_id, CONCAT_WS(',',     
    @keyword_ids, keyword_ids), keyword_ids)), 
         @prev_item_id := item_id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY item_id;
```

Comment: Nice solution, seems to work fine, now I have to adapt it in Java with multiple queries. If you have any ideas, I will gladly hear them, since it doesn't accept two *String* queries. Thanks!

Comment: @pathat0r If the solution above works, then presumably it can be be rewritten as follows: `SELECT  MAX(@keyword_ids := IF(@prev_item_id = item_id, CONCAT_WS(',',     
    @keyword_ids, keyword_ids), keyword_ids)), 
         @prev_item_id := item_id
FROM mytable
   , (SELECT @prev_item_id := NULL) vars
GROUP BY item_id;`