# MySQL select all rows with the same group of id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using using MySql 5.7.18 and PHP 7.

I have this table :

```
id | object_id | item_id
-------------------------
1       1          2
2       1          3
3       1          4

4       2          5
5       2          3

6       3          2
7       3          3
8       3          4

9       4          2

10      5          1
11      5          3
12      5          5

13      6          2
14      6          3
15      6          4
```

So I need to select the reference object by id, for example I'll take the object_id `1` and take his items, so in my code I'll get :

```
$object_id = 1;
$item_ids = [2, 3, 4];
```

Now I want to get all `object_id` who have the same group of `item_id`. So here I need to get the `object_id 3 and 6` because all of them have the same `item_id` than the object 1.

Another example if I have the `object_id` 2 in reference I'll get no result because there are no row with the same group ids.

It is possible to do that with SQL query or I have to do it in my code ?

Comment: *"

I'm using using MySql 4.7.3 and PHP 7."* MySQL 4 with PHP 7 ? .... Does that even work pretty sure that PHP 7 MySQL client does not supports that old MySQL 4 connection protocol anymore.....

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry, bad copy paste xD

Comment: It was phpMyAdmin version x_x

Comment: mistakes happen, it might be even the case MySQL 4.7.3 never existed, i forgot the versions before MySQL 5.5 more or less as the manuals on MySQL websites are removed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it seems possible by concatenation, here it is:

```
select a.* from (
    select object_id, group_concat(item_id order by id separator '-') as item_list 
    from test group by object_id
) a where a.item_list = '2-3-4'
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6360bc/6

---

If you want to query by object ID:

```
select a.* from (
    select object_id, group_concat(item_id order by id separator '-') as item_list 
    from test group by object_id
) a where a.item_list = (
    select group_concat(item_id order by id separator '-') 
    from test where object_id = 1
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479138/group-concat-in-old-mysql-version

Comment: but never mind mine comments ... topicstarter made a copy/paste error :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes I was going to delete my answer as I don't have mySQL 4.7 :)

Comment: So in my code I have to convert my array like the group_concat ?

Comment: ıf you want I can modify it to use object id instead?

Comment: But now I have to go home :) Later maybe.

Comment: Use the object id in the where condition ? How you do that ?

Comment: Thank you so much !